# shell script while loop with sed command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, while-loop

I have 2 files, want to create a new file based on the 2 files(testfile1 and 2).By reading the first file line by line from testfile1.txt and based on string matched between special char @ and its value from testfile2.txt. More detail below.

testfile1.txt

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
## END :: end of file #
```

testfile2.txt

```
mysite.mw_path=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
mysite.mw_brkr_path=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/
```

testfile3.txt ( testfile 1 and 3 are same)

test_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  pattern1=$(echo "$line" | awk -F@ '{print $2}')
      if [ -n "$pattern1" ]; then
         pattern2=$(grep "$pattern1" $2 | awk -F"=" '{ print $2 }')
         sed "s|$pattern1|$pattern2|g" testfile3.txt > output_21aug.txt
      fi
done < "$1"
```

testfile1 and testfile3 are same.

```
ri@my_server ~]$ ./test_script.sh testfile1.txt testfile2.txt

ri@my_server ~]$ cat output_21aug.txt
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@myaccount.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@myaccount.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/@
## END :: end of file ##
```

I'm getting the above output, I'm expecting the output like below

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/@
## END :: end of file ##
```

Please help me fixing my script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have a testfile3 that's the same as testfile1, and where does it fit in?

Comment: to be clear, you want to _keep_ the `@` symbols that indicate a parameter substitution?

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is not the best tool for this, but you can certainly just do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {for( i in a) gsub("@"i"@", a[i])}1 ' FS== testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

You scan the 2nd file and build a lookup table, then iterate over the lookup table for each line of the first file.  Terribly inefficient, but easier than trying to pick the index out of the line. (It can be done with `awk`, but it's so much easier with `perl` that I am not even willing to go remember how to do it.)  If your data is small enough, this should be fine.  If the processing takes too long (more than .5 seconds), spend time on efficiency. (eg, use `perl`)

On the other hand, avoiding the loop is not too bad:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} match($0, "@[^@]*@"){
        i=substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2 "@");
        gsub("@"i"@", a[i]);  }1 ' FS== testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

The `FNR==NR` expression is a standard awk idiom for restricting the command block to the first file, where we build the lookup table. In the second file, we use `match` to see if there is a pair of `@` signs, and then pull out the text between them using RSTART and RLENGTH.  `gsub` does the substitution.  This is neither robust nor reliable, but should suit your immediate needs.

Comment: if the testfile2.txt is like this

 

mysite.mw_path=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
mysite.mw_brkr_path=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/
mysite.mw_url=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/=mysite/images/

 

in the 3rd line "=mysite/images/" is getting ommitted  

 

any suggestion here please..!  I don't have 'perl' knowledge :(

Comment: @Richa The additional `=` sign does introduce a hiccup, since awk is splitting that line on =.  Should be easy enough to fix.  edited

Answer (score 3):

Here's an other `awk` idea:

```bash
awk -F'=' -v OFS='=' '
    NR == FNR { a["@" $1 "@"] = "@" $2 "@"; next }
    NF == 2 && $2 ~ /^@[^@]*@$/ { $2 = a[$2] }
    1
' testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/@
## END :: end of file #
```